# Renderizando Array Dinâmico - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

Estou tentando renderizar um array dinâmico no meu HTML, a cada clique no ("+") ele gera um novo item no FormArray.

Os novos campos estão sendo gerados da forma correta, mas ao adicionar um arquivo o nome dele não é exibido (continua "Nenhum arquivo selecionado").

Acredito que isso é pelo fato de ao atualizar o as informações do FormArray ele renderiza novamente o FormArray, mantendo as informações mas não exibindo no HTML o nome do arquivo.

Alguém tem algum ideia de solução para esse problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

protocolo.component.ts

```js
  filterForm = new FormGroup({
   IdProtocolo: new FormControl(),
   Documentos: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ]);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.filterForm.get('Documentos') as FormArray;
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup{
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      filename: '',
      filetype: '',
      value: ''
    })
  }
  
  addItem(){
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }

  removeItem(index){
    if(this.items.length > 1) {
      this.items.removeAt(index);
    }
  }
  
  onFileChange(event: any, index: any) {

    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
        this.items.at(index).patchValue({
          filename: file.name,
          filetype: file.type,
          value: (reader.result as string).split(',')[1]
        })
    }
  }
```

protocolo.component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of filterForm.value.Documentos; let i = index;">
  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="file" formControlName="Documentos" (change)="onFileChange($event, i)">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <button class="btn btn-success-tce" (click)="addItem()">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success-tce" (click)="removeItem(i)"style="margin-left: 5px">-</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não falta identificar para o input qual o indice correspondente dele?